# Error of TfidfVectorizer on cleaned text dataset

Tags: python, data-mining, sentiment-analysis, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to vectorize a sentiment data set. It has review text and sentimentlabel given. When I try to vectorize the data set It gives an error called **'LazyCorpusLoader' object is not iterable**

The reviews were cleaned as follows.

- remove html tags
- tokenize text to remove punctuations
- remove stop words
- POS tagging
- lemmatize text

After these my dataframe reviewdataset_df has following columns:

1. reviews_clean->cleaned review text
2. SENTIMENT-> a sentiment label as positive or negative

then I split the data set using below code,

```
#splitting data set into training and testing
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test =train_test_split(reviewDataset_Df.head(10000).review_clean,reviewDataset_Df.head(10000).SENTIMENT,test_size=0.20,random_state=0,shuffle=True)                                          

print('Training data count:'+str(len(X_train)))
print('Test data count:'+str(len(X_test)))
```

That worked well.

Then I use vectorizer using following code.

```
#vectorizer
tfidf=TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True,min_df=3,stop_words=english,norm='l2',encoding='utf-8',ngram_range=(1,3))
print("rr")
train_features=tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)
test_features=tfidf.transform(X_test)
train_labels=Y_train
test_labels=Y_test
```

This gives an error as 
**return frozenset(stop)
TypeError: 'LazyCorpusLoader' object is not iterable**

I searched and tried on some solutions which didn't worked. How to overcome this error. I need to vectorize the data set to train for a recommendation system.

note: I searched through internet and read similar question in stackoverflow but couldn't find a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a proper error trace we can only guess.

Since the error involves `stop` my guess is that your variable `english` - that isn't in the code you shared at all - is inappropriately set up, and not a set of words.

You probably meant to use `stop_words="english"` instead.